# Outlook search query not behaving as expected

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-filter

I've used various versions of Outlook desktop (not part of Office 365) for decades, but have always run into inexplicabilities with the search syntax.  I find the GUI query too slow and restrictive, so I press Ctrl+E and type the query in.  Things like this work fine:

"to:WhatChaMaCallit OR from:WhatChaMaCallit" (without quotes)

Here, WhatChaMaCallit is the name of an app, and it is also the name of the OEM company behind the app.  The above query finds all messages to or from the OEM.  The following, however, does not work as expected:

"WhatChaMaCallit AND NOT (to:WhatChaMaCallit OR from:WhatChaMaCallit)" (without quotes)

Here, I want to find messages that make reference to the WhatChaMaCallit app, excluding messages to or from the OEM.  Instead, the results include all messages that mention WhatChaMaCallit, including messages to or from the OEM.

Can you imagine composing a SQL query whose syntax will be interpretted in an arbitrary manner?  It would be impossible to use.  Over the years, I've hunted down many webpages about the syntax, e.g., https://www.lifewire.com/outlook-search-operators-1170667.  For some reason, Outlook seems to ignore such rules for all but the simplest queries.

Is there an *authoritative* and *complete* source on the search syntax?  Authoritative meaning that its content is 100% accurate, and complete meaning that all operators are covered.

Comment: According to my test, in the outlook client, it seems that only the target conditions (for example, from someone, including a field) can be correctly searched. However, when it comes to exceptional conditions (such as not from someone and not containing a field), you cannot search.

Comment: So bizarre.  Microsoft's [own page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-search-in-outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da) shows the use of NOT.  [This](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/boolean-search-with-multiple-criteria) and [this](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/searchcommands.htm) page show NOT applied to entire criteria, e.g., NOT from:Amazon (in a Boolean search with brackets).  That's why we need an authoritative (i.e., accurate) reference for this query language, which Microsoft's page seems not to be, including any limitations of the operators.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the last reply I got was from searching in advanced search > query builder. After my second attempt, I found that I could successfully search by directly entering the following fields in the search box：

```
NOT (to: test OR from: test) and about: test
```

(“test” can be replaced with other fields you want to search)

Comment: Thanks, Christy. For me, it's inconsistent. First, I leave no space after the colons. Second, I put the entire email address after `to:` and `from:`.  Together with `about:`, this find some messages without the OEM as sender/receiver, but it includes messages where the `about:` term is *not* in the subject. So it doesn't provide the precise control desired, though it *seems* to work for the particular query in the question. I'm not sure how to confirm that with the volume of email that I have, and without a "ground truth" method of correctly querying.

Comment: Just as problematic, howevever, is that using `subject:` in place of `about:` does *not* work; it returns messages with the OEM as sender/receiver.  This is *very* odd because [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-search-in-outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da) describes them both as doing the same thing.

Comment: If you want to find the emails with specific fields in Subject, just search: "NOT (to: test OR from: test) and subject: test". When you use "NOT (to: test OR from: test) and about: test", you can only find the emails with the specific fields in email body.

Comment: I understand that individual queries may work as expected, but I'm really hoping to find a complete and correct specification of the query language. The Microsoft page I cited in my last comment says that `about:` is for finding things in the subject line, so it is incorrect.

Comment: Using the logic about in your last comment, I should also be able to query `subject:OEMname AND NOT(to:OEMemail OR from:OEMemail)` to find messages with `OEMname` in the subject line, but not messages to/from the OEM. This doesn't work, since the findings include messages to/from the OEM. So a complete and authoritative reference for the query language is still needed. I'm not trying to fault you, and I appreciate your time in responding. It is possible that the query engine is simply not consistent enough for a reference to be established.

Comment: Why have you posted two answers? Are the two solutions distinct?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, when you use "about", the items with "test" appears in the subject line, body, or attachment contents will be shown. And based on my test on searching "NOT (to: test OR from: test) and about: test", I can search the items with "test" in subject line and not from "test" or to "test", which is consistent with the functionality described in the official documentation.(Note here that I use the email address to replace the "test" field.)
[image]

Sorry that I don't understand what you mean. You can't find the correct results by using the search instructions provided by me, right?

Comment: My apologies, Christy. I was wrong about the keyword "about:". This works `about:keyword AND NOT (to:Email OR from:Email)`. However, my question is about an authoritative, correct, and complete reference for the syntax in general. It seems to me that the 2nd query in my originally posted question should yield the same results as the one above, but it doesn't. So when I compose queries, I'm never really sure what works as it should, and I don't know how much I trust the completeness of the returns. Is there such a reference?

Comment: I can fully understand your feelings. But as far as I know, the use of outlook search keywords is all in this article(https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-search-in-outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da). For highly demanding search, we can only think of ways based on this. By the way, if you think my reply above is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.

Comment: Christy, the examples that fail are not highly demanding searches.  They are basic Boolean expressions.  I appreciate the time that you put into responding, but the correct answer seems to be that there is no authoritative, correct, and complete description of the query language.  Possibly because the search function doesn't behave according to consistent rules.